# How to make optparse in python other languages

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I want make compute Cyclomatic Complexity(CC) program in python.

And I use compiler(ASTVisitor) module when I comute CC in python codes.

But I don't know available module other languages such as C/C++, Java.

please tell me, I can use module alike compiler(ASTVisiter) other languages,

or module that make AST(Abstract Syntax Tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) for c/c++, which has python bindings.